# Generate random numbers 1-12 without null?

Tags: java, arrays, random, null

Hopefully the title explains what I want. I want a set of numbers 1-12 in a random order but not get a null result.

Here is my code:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[12];

    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i+1; //With this not being i+1, I get 0-11. Like this, I get null-12 and no 1.

        if (arr[i] ==  null)
        {
            arr[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

And here is what I get as an output:

```
[null, 5, 3, 10, 7, 2, 9, 4, 6, 12, 8, 11]
```

How can I convert the null because my if statement does nothing?

Comment: Array indices start at 0! And you never set element 0...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not initializing the first element in you array. Start with i = 0 in you loop, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from 0 instead of 1

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

Comment: Whoops. I must have accidentally tried 2 ways of getting 1-12 and forgot to remove the first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays` are `0 based`, so the first elements should be start from `0` index, not `1`

So try to change your code like:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

for more details read more about [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 1):

start your for loop at `0`

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing loop variable i to 1 as a result the array arr[0] is never assigned a value which is by default null. Your loop should be for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)